# VBA bold specific string

Tags: html, vba, bold

I am trying to set up a macro through Excel to send emails. I need some parts to be bolded but I cannot figure out how to bold a temp string, tempString = sh.Range("E" & i).Value

Comment: Try enclosing the string with an html <b> tag

Comment: Gives me a 
Compile error: Expected: expression

Comment: `tempString = "<b>" & sh.Range("E" & i).Value & "</b>"` - but keep in mind those will only work when rendered as HTML. So, in Outlook, make sure you are using `.HTMLBody` and not the normal `.Body`

Comment: It's really hard to know what to tell you with such limited information. Perhaps if you provided a bit more specific context in what you have actually tried instead of describing it that would help.